# How to generate a two-circumference curve?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, bezier-curve

I have these two circles.
[image]

And I would like to generate a curve like this, what is the most exact way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Rotate each circle 45° (causing them to have an overlapping anchor point)
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) to click anchors and delete them, leaving appropriate segments.
- Select the middle 2 anchor points and join them (`Object > Path > Join`)

[image]

Rather than rotating the circles, you could also use `Object > Path > Add Anchors` to create additional anchor points for smaller segments. New anchor points are added halfway between existing anchor points. In this case, you may not need to rotate the circles. They will inherently gain an overlapping anchor point.

Comment: Wow, I thought it was much more complicated, thank you very much

Comment: Funny... I thought it would be easier to do the shape with 2 circles on top of each other first then rotate the final shape 45º!

Comment: @Luciano equal amount of work

Comment: @Luciano I merely started where the question stated it started... but yeah.. stacked then rotate the final curve. Basically the same thing - using a common anchor position on both circles.